# Spacy sentence tokenization very slow and faulty

Tags: python, spacy

I wanted to use spacy to do sentence segmentation for the german wikipedia but the problem is it is very slow. The wikipedia after some cleaning is about 55,00 files, each file around 1 Mb. It took around 24 hours to process half of them and write the segmented text to new files, and the sentences are not properly segmented as well

```
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
for file in files:

    file_path = join(rootdir, path, file) 
    new_file_name = join(output_dir, file + ".txt")

    with open(file_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        with open(new_file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
            content = f.readlines()
            doc = ""
            for i in range(len(content)):
                doc = doc + content[i]        
            doc = nlp(doc)
            sentences = list(doc.sents)
            for i in range(len(sentences)):
                new_file.write(sentences[i].string.strip() + '\n')
            new_file.write('\n')
            doc = ""
```

There are problems with the segmentation itself, for example: this input paragraph:

"Maria I. (England)

Maria I. Tudor (), auch "Maria die Katholische" oder "Maria die Blutige" (* 18. Februar 1516 in Greenwich; † 17. November 1558 im St James’s Palace), war von 1553 bis 1558 Königin von England und Irland und der vierte Monarch des Hauses Tudor. Sie war die Tochter des Königs Heinrichs VIII. und seiner ersten Frau Katharina von Aragon. Als ihr Vater die Ehe vom englischen Klerus für nichtig erklären ließ und Anne Boleyn heiratete, wurde Maria dauerhaft von ihrer Mutter getrennt, zum königlichen Bastard erklärt und von der Thronfolge ausgeschlossen."

has this output:

"Maria I. (England)
Maria I. Tudor

(), auch "Maria die Katholische" oder "Maria

die Blutige

" (*

18. Februar 1516 in Greenwich;

† 17. November 1558 im St James’s Palace), war von 1553 bis 1558 Königin von England und Irland und der vierte Monarch des Hauses Tudor.

Sie war die Tochter des Königs Heinrichs

VIII. und seiner ersten Frau Katharina von Aragon.

Als ihr Vater die Ehe vom englischen Klerus für nichtig erklären ließ und Anne Boleyn heiratete, wurde Maria dauerhaft von ihrer Mutter getrennt, zum königlichen Bastard erklärt und von der Thronfolge ausgeschlossen."

**Please note that in the ouput I write every sentence in a new line**